# Ip xfrm state command displays key information, which may cause information leakage. Is there any way to prevent users from viewing key information?

Tags: ip, secret-key, ipsec, strongswan, disclosure

Ip xfrm state command displays key information, which may cause information leakage.In the following, the **auth-trunc hmac** and **enc cbc** will cause key information leakage. Is there any way to prevent users from viewing key information in any case?
Although this command must be executed by the root user, but I think the IPSec key information configured by non-root users should not be disclosed.

ip xfrm state:
src 192.168.244.52 dst 192.168.244.53
proto esp spi 0x12345678 reqid 305419896 mode tunnel
replay-window 0
auth-trunc hmac(sha256) 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234 96
enc cbc(aes) 0x0000123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
src 192.168.244.53 dst 192.168.244.52
proto esp spi 0x12345678 reqid 305419896 mode tunnel
replay-window 0
auth-trunc hmac(sha256) 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234 96
enc cbc(aes) 0x0000123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x196, bitmap 0x00000000
sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0

I saw that could use ip xfrm state list nokeys commond to prevent key information from being printed, but that didn't solve my problem.

xfrm: add option to hide keys in state output：
https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20190118191217.131649-2-benedictwong@google.com/

Comment: Newer kernel allow masking the keys via kernel lockdown (`/sys/kernel/security/lockdown`). Note that IKE daemons might need the keys to update SAs when moving to a different IP address.

Comment: @ecdsa: I use Linux 5.10.0 version, added the lockdown=confidentiality parameter to the kernel command line through grub2. After linux startup, the /sys/kernel/security/lockdown file has displayed as: none integrity [confidentiality]. This indicates that the lockdown confidentiality has taken effect, but the key information in plaintext is still displayed after i run the "ip xfrm state" command.

Comment: You need at least 5.11.

Comment: @ecdsa: I update kernel to 6.4.2, it works, the key information display as 0. tks. ; ）